# An easier way to test a valid username

Tags: ruby, regex, validation

I have the following requirement for valid usernames:

1. Only alphanumeric characters and -
2. Must not start with a -

I wrote this regex ([on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/7eMwINodOB)):

```
/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]|[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+/
```

Is there a better to test this requirement other than to iterate through all the possible scenarios? I'm doing something like this.

```
  # There much more, but for brevity's sake I'm only including a few
  illegal_chars = [ "~", "!", "@", "#", "$"]

  illegal_chars.each do |char|
    test "username does not accept #{char}" do
      user = users(:homer)
      user.username = "name#{char}"
      refute user.valid?, "Username should not be valid"
    end
  end
```

I'll repeat for cases where `#{char}` is at the beginning and end of the word.

1. Am I testing too much? Is there a better way? Running 70 or 80 tests for something like this seems excessive.
2. As an aside, can my regex be expressed better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex looks wrong, see my link below.

If your functional requirement is that usernames match a certain regex, then your tests should reflect that. It is wrong to test a bunch of edge cases that a generic regex catches.

[See this](https://regex101.com/r/uZ4hM4/2). All you need in your test is to do:

```
username_regex = /^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*$/i
passing_usernames = ['passing','pAsSing-PASS-'.....]
failing_usernames = ['-failing','failing#'....]
passing_usernames.each { |username| assert_match username_regex, username}
failing_usernames.each { |username| assert_no_match username_regex, username }
```

If you're getting your username from somewhere else then just plug that in the same way.

Comment: For Ruby, [your regex will not work](http://rubular.com/r/CpsVASmDNx), but it's an easy fix: You need to add A-Z: `^[a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+$`

Comment: @Mohamad I apologize, I forgot to copy part of the regex. You don't need A-Z in the regex, you can append `i` (for case **i**nsensitive) after the slash. Of course, both work, but this way is shorter.

Comment: Assuming usernames can be of length one, you might want to change `+` to `*` in `username_regex`.

Comment: You could also use a POSIX character class (which can only be used within brackets): `username_regex = /^[:alnum:][[:alnum:]-]*$/`.